# Running the /usr/bin/time from perl

Tags: perl, time

I'm trying to do some very-rough benchmarking and so I'd like to run the `time` command from my script. I have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

   use strict;

   my $command = "/usr/bin/time -f \"%U,%S,%E,%P,%K,%M\" ...";
   my $stats = `$command`;
   print "stats: $stats\n";
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the result of the command is never assigned to `$stats`. When I execute the script, I get something like the following:

```
0.15,0.03,0:00.44,43%,0,143808
stats:
```

So it looks like it runs the `time` command successfully, but prints out the value to `STDOUT` instead of assigning the value to `$stats`. When I use another command, like `ls`, it seems to work as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Using `qq[/usr/bin/time ...]` can avoid a lot of escaping. [(qq docs)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`time` prints to stderr.

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%U,%S,%E,%P,%K,%M" echo foo >/dev/null
0.00,0.00,0:00.03,10%,0,2352

$ /usr/bin/time -f "%U,%S,%E,%P,%K,%M" echo foo >/dev/null 2>/dev/null


$
```

So just add `2>&1` to your command.

Answer (score 5):

`time` writes to standard error, so you need to redirect it to standard output to capture it with Perl's backticks

```
 my $command = "/usr/bin/time -f \"%U,%S,%E,%P,%K,%M\" ... 2>&1";
```